# How to do looping on date and Time

Tags: r, datetime, for-loop

I want apply looping for every hour over week of data, lets say start date will be  `1/04/2019 00:00:00` and end date will be `8/04/2019 00:00:00` for querying to get data from bigquery.

```
sql_machine1 <- "SELECT * FROM `lasprod2.iot_data` WHERE customer = \"client_name\" and asset = \"machine1\" and timestamp between \"01/04/2019 00:00:00\" and \"01/04/2019 01:00:00\""

query_machine1 <- bq_project_query(x = project,query = sql_machine1)
machine1 <- bq_table_download(query_machine1)
```

Looping should support below o/p format

output format:

[image]

Comment: You are more likely to get a good answer if you show your effort.
Also read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see how to provide a minimal  complete and verifiable example

Answer (score 0):

One idea...

```
# Make a sequence of hours
date.seq <- seq(from = ISOdatetime(year = 2019, month = 4, day = 1, hour = 1, min = 1, sec = 1),
                to = ISOdatetime(year = 2019, month = 4, day = 8, hour = 1, min = 1, sec = 1),
                by = '1 hour')

# Use these in a loop
for(my_date in date.seq){
  # do something
}
```